# HTML Validation with Golang

Tags: html, json, go

Within my API I have a POST end point. One of the expected parameters being posted to that end point is a block of (loosely) valid HTML.

The POST will be in the format of JSON.

Within golang how can I ensure that the HTML which is posted is valid? I have been looking for something for a few days now and still haven't managed to find anything?

The term "valid" is kind of loose. I trying to ensure that tags are opened and closed, speech marks are in the right places etc.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an HTML parser.

Answer (score 8):

A bit late to the game, but here are a couple of parsers in Go that will work if you just want to validate the structure of the HTML (eg. you don't care if a div is inside a span, which is not allowed but is a schema level problem):

#### x/net/html

The [`golang.org/x/net/html`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html) package contains a *very* loose parser. Almost anything will result in valid HTML, similar to what a lot of web browsers try to do (eg. it will ignore problems with unescaped values in many cases).
For example, something like `<span>></span>` will likely validate (I didn't check this particular one, I just made it up) as a span with the '>' character in it.

It can be used something like this:

```
r := strings.NewReader(`<span>></span>`)
z := html.NewTokenizer(r)
for {
    tt := z.Next()
    if tt == html.ErrorToken {
        err := z.Err()
        if err == io.EOF {
            // Not an error, we're done and it's valid!
            return nil
        }
        return err
    }
}
```

### encoding/xml

If you need something a tiny bit more strict, but which is still okay for HTML you can configure an [`xml.Decoder`](https://godoc.org/encoding/xml#Decoder) to work with HTML (this is what I do, it lets me be a bit more flexible about how strict I want to be in any given situation):

```
r := strings.NewReader(`<html></html>`)
d := xml.NewDecoder(r)

// Configure the decoder for HTML; leave off strict and autoclose for XHTML
d.Strict = false
d.AutoClose = xml.HTMLAutoClose
d.Entity = xml.HTMLEntity
for {
    tt, err := d.Token()
    switch err {
    case io.EOF:
        return nil // We're done, it's valid!
    case nil:
    default:
        return err // Oops, something wasn't right
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You check that the HTML blob provided parses correctly using [`html.Parse`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Parse) from [this package](https://golang.org/x/net/html). For validation only, all you have to do is check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

**use golang.org/x/net/html**

```
import (
    "strings"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func isValidHTML(htmlStr string) bool {
    _, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(htmlStr))
    return err == nil
}
```